# Vertical Align Text to a Floated Image that is on the Left

Tags: css, responsive-design, vertical-alignment

Now I know there are similar questions posted, but I'm looking for a solution for pixel perfection.

Sandbox: http://jsfiddle.net/unqc4a0f/1/

Problem trying to solve:
[image: Problem]

Attempted code:

```
.mi{float:left; width:150px;height:200px;padding-right:10px;/*margin-top:3px;*/}
.mt{float:left; width:400px;margin:0;}
```

In the past I've used the padding/margin hacks to push the image or the text objects down a few pixels to make them visually align at the top edge. And by visually I mean that I know that the fonts have a size and line height, but even taking that into account, the height of the actual font characters may include some space. This you can see in my example above. I've also —based on other threads here —tried using line-height, and although that did achieve pixel perfect alignment, it mangled the the vertical line spacing of the entire paragraph.

My question essentially is whether to continue using the padding/margin hacks or is there a more 'legit' solution. I ask this in regards to building layouts that are responsive and then having no issues with uniform layouts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there's any alternative to the pixel-wrangling you're currently doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realize it's an old question but...

In CSS one can use a `::before` element add a negative `margin-top` value to it.

Specifically, I wanted to share this [Interactive Text-Crop tool](http://text-crop.eightshapes.com/) I found that helps create a SASS mixin for this purpose.

The gist in this tool is that you remove the capital height from the (font-size * line-height) and then divide by two. But that is a simplification of how your font may or may not be structured.

In reality - There is no "pixel-perfect" answer because when it comes down to it, the physical structure of fonts doesn't always match their `font-size` and different font-families at the same font-sizes can still look taller or shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `float` use a `display:table;` layout for a perfect inline placement and vertical alignment.

It only requires that you wrap them within an element...

[**Updated JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/unqc4a0f/2/)

```css
.wrapper {
    display: table;
}

.mi{width:200px;height:200px;display: table-cell;}
.mt{display: table-cell;vertical-align:middle;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.thehollywoodnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2839335-morgan_freeman_wallpaper_4_normal.jpg" class="mi">
    <p class="mt">Join me in San Diego at the Global Event for Data-Driven Engagement Marketers. DMA is doing great work to protect marketers around the world, come and hear from leading marketers how DMA is enabling them to NOT MARKET ALONE</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi LcSalazar, your sample did not solve my problem, the text is not aligning pixel perfect to the top of the image. I'm on chrome and this is what I'm [seeing](http://i.imgur.com/0IuROXT.png)

Answer (score 1):

The space is supposed to be there it normally comes from line height which is something you need. If you font size is 14px and you reduce the linee-height to 11px you see the gap will vanish from the top, but the text will look very cramped..

Sometimes to get pixel perfect you have to just tweak like you have with the margin on the image..